# How can I add a contact to a list/audience in Mailchimp using its own library via Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mailchimp, unhandled, unhandled-promise-rejection

The code below is the API call to add a contact to a list/audience programmatically using Node JS and the Mailchimp library. Documentation is found on: https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/create-your-first-audience/#add-a-contact-to-an-audience

```
const listId = "YOUR_LIST_ID";
const subscribingUser = {
 firstName: "Prudence",
 lastName: "McVankab",
 email: "prudence.mcvankab@example.com"
};

async function run() {
const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember(listId, {
  email_address: subscribingUser.email,
  status: "subscribed",
  merge_fields: {
    FNAME: subscribingUser.firstName,
    LNAME: subscribingUser.lastName
  }
});

console.log(
  `Successfully added contact as an audience member. The contact's id is ${
    response.id
  }.`
);
}
run();
```

Here's how I implemented the code in my app.js

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
 const firstName = req.body.firstName;
 const lastName = req.body.lastName;
 const email = req.body.email;

 const apiAudienceName = "Sample Tech Newsletter Subscription";

 const listId = apiAudienceName;
 const subscribingUser = {
  firstName: firstName,
  lastName: lastName,
  email: email
 };

 async function run() {
   const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember(listId, {
     email_address: subscribingUser.email,
     status: "subscribed",
     merge_fields: {
       FNAME: subscribingUser.firstName,
       LNAME: subscribingUser.lastName
     }
   });

   console.log(`Successfully added contact as an audience member. The contact's id is ${response.id}.`);

 }

 run();
});
```

To me, I did the exact requirement of the Mailchimp server to add to my created list but this code is throwing an error saying **"Unhandled promise rejection"**. I've tried to do my research of course but as a beginner in this language, I don't really quite grasp what is needed for me to make this happen. If someone could correct me or show me the error in my code, I would appreciate it. Thank you very much!

NOTE: I was able to make this work by using HTTP request module. But for this time, I wanted to learn how to follow a documentation and use their given code and library. To me, it seems that I did that but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Wrap your async code inside a `try/catch` block and manage the possible errors to get ride of that message

Comment: @FLC I tried doing so and it did eliminate the error. Though I know that this doesn't solve my problem of not being  able to post in the Mailchimp API. May I ask what does `try/catch` do when it comes to "promises". Is it use to "only" catch the errors? If so, why does it not logged the suppose error? I  am having trouble understanding as this was the suggestion of most of the community in dealing with this. I appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through research and help from the course community that I am in, I found the problem in my code. I hope this helps someone who's dealing/will potentially deal with the same problem.

```
const apiAudienceName = "Sample Tech Newsletter Subscription";

const listId = apiAudienceName;
```

As you can see in the above code, I am inputting the **"list/audience name"** that I have created in the Mailchimp website into the `listID` variable. The problem is that the Mailchimp API is expecting the `listID` and not the name of the list that you have in the Mailchimp API.

The answer that solved this problem was getting the `list/audience ID` from your account in the Mailchimp website and using it as an input. The `list/audience ID` is an alphanumeric characters provided by the Mailchimp server.

If you want a detailed guide on finding your `list/audience ID`, check this [link](https://mailchimp.com/help/find-audience-id/).

Here's a sample code that solved this problem:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
 const firstName = req.body.firstName;
 const lastName = req.body.lastName;
 const email = req.body.email;

 const listId = "1a2b3c4d5e777";
 const subscribingUser = {
  firstName: firstName,
  lastName: lastName,
  email: email
 };

 async function run() {
  const response = await mailchimp.lists.addListMember(listId, {
   email_address: subscribingUser.email,
   status: "subscribed",
   merge_fields: {
     FNAME: subscribingUser.firstName,
     LNAME: subscribingUser.lastName
   }
 });

 console.log(`Successfully added contact as an audience member. The contact's id is ${response.id}.`);

 }

 run();
});
```

Comment: thank you for the follow up! this saved me so much time

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [subsribi](https://subscribi.io/) yet? it has a simple API you can use to add subscribers to your list using JavaScript,

- Example:

  const data = {
  email:"sarah@mail.com", //* required
  username:"sarah", //optional
  listId:'[LIST_ID]',

  ```
  }
    const url = 'https://api.subscribi.io/v1/subscribers/add'
    fetch(url,{
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'secret_key':'MY_SECRET_KEY' //  Go the the settings and generate a key
      }, 
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    }).then(response =>{
      console.log(response)
      /*
      {
        "data": {
            "name": "sarah",
            "email": "sarah@mail.com",
            "createdAt": "2020-09-25T19:41:07.350Z",
            "subscribed": true
        },
        "ok": true,
        "status": "success"
    }

      */
    }).catch(error=>{
      console.error(error)
    })
  ```

Comment: Hi. I haven't tried this yet but maybe I'll give it a try sometime. Either way, I'm not going to flag this as an answer because it's not. This is more of a comment in this case. Still, thank you for this!